# InvokeAll timeout interrupt

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

**Question**:

How do I make a series of threads that have timed out with `invokeAll` stop execution.

**Background**:

I have a list of `callables` I want to wait to complete. However, if they don't complete within a set time (say a second) I want to cancel them. This seems easy enough with

```
executor.invokeAll(callables, 1000l, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

So after a second it will time out just fine and I can go on with my day. However in the background the threads are still active and potentially executing some pieces of code. Essentially they are not interrupted which I do not want to happen - I want the threads to stop executing.

Is there any way to use the futures list returned to stop the threads after `invokeAll` has hit its timeout?

Comment: The documentation says that when returned tasks that are not completed are cancelled. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29

Comment: I think they're cancelled but they are still live and can continue logging even after `invokeAll` has stopped blocking

Comment: What are the threads doing? There's all kinds of possible reasons why a thread does not respond to interruption (Blocking IO, code eating the interruption, code ignoring the interruption, waiting to enter a synchronized block...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecutorService` was designed to support [cancellation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) of tasks that respond to [interruption.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) So, the proper way to do this is by making your `Callable` implementations notice that they've been interrupted.

If your task is purely computational, or if it loops frequently, calling a third-party library, this is easy. Somewhere in your task, you'll have a loop that looks something like:

```
while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
  /* Keep going */
}
```

Of course, you might test other task-specific conditions in your loop too, but you should be testing the interrupted state of the current thread.

Calling [`interrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted--) will clear the interrupted status. Calling [`Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted--) will preserve the interrupted status. For worker threads in an `ExecutorService`, keeping the interrupted status doesn't matter too much—the service is interrupting its own threads, and when its thread returns from your task, the service clears the status without looking at it. But, it's a good habit to adopt, so that your code will work well if it is incorporated in a task. To re-assert the interrupted status after catching an `InterruptedException` or detecting it with `Thread.interrupted()`, simply call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`.

If the task is a long-running call to a third-party library that doesn't support interruption, or a blocking call to an uninterruptible I/O operation, your "task" is much more difficult. You may be out of luck altogether, or you might be able to find a kludge to abort the operation asynchronously.

For example, if you create a `Socket`, and pass it (or its streams) to your task, you could asynchronously close the socket. If `invokeAll` times out, the caller would need additional code to close the socket.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have it *both* ways.

The ExecutorService "framework" allows you to only think in terms of `Callable` objects and `Future` results. This abstraction **hides** all the low level details of the threads involved. Thus: even if it would be possible, your idea would most likely be a "dirty hack".

In other words: if you want low-level, direct access to the threads doing something - then you might have to use your own "thread pooling" implementation.

Middle ground: keep in mind that these threads execute **your** Callable/Runnable instances. You could of course think up something where those objects *regularly* check some sort of "command queue". And when the queue contains a *cancel request* - then *your* code in the Callable stops doing its work.

Comment: Your comment makes sense but I really wouldn't haven't assumed this would be the standard behaviour when I gave `invokeAll` a timeout. It's very strange that the threads that keeping running are "effectively stopped" but not interrupted up until you invoke something which throws an `InterruptedException`. There should be a higher level way of polling for an interrupted exception

Comment: The point is: "interrupting" threads isn't something that you "commonly" do in Java. When you have long running Runnable/Callable code, then you have that code check some "cancel" flag somehow.